# Generating wrong unixtimestamp in informix

Tags: java, stored-procedures, informix, unix-timestamp

I am using following code to generate unix time stamp in java.

```
 Date d1=new Date();
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(d1.getTime()));
    System.out.println(d1.getTime());
```

which will give me an output as 1382016125183 (for the date 2013-10-17 18:52:05.183)

Now I want exactly same timestamp in informix so I am using the following stored procedure to generate the timestamp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE to_unix_time(d DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)
                                DEFAULT CURRENT YEAR TO FRACTION(5))
            RETURNING DECIMAL(18,5);
    DEFINE n DECIMAL(18,5);
    DEFINE i1 INTERVAL DAY(9) TO DAY;
    DEFINE i2 INTERVAL SECOND(6) TO FRACTION(5);
    DEFINE s1 CHAR(15);
    DEFINE s2 CHAR(15);
    LET i1 = EXTEND(d, YEAR TO DAY) - DATETIME(1970-01-01) YEAR TO DAY;
    LET s1 = i1;
    LET i2 = EXTEND(d, HOUR TO FRACTION(5)) -
                DATETIME(00:00:00.00000) HOUR TO FRACTION(5);
    LET s2 = i2;
    LET n = s1 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + s2;
    RETURN n;
END PROCEDURE;
```

I am entering the same date in this procedure as I got in java. But it will generate a wrong timestamp  1381968067925 for the date 2013-10-17 18:52:05.183.

I want both timestamps to be equal in both the cases - how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those two results is 48057258. Divide that by 60/60/1000 and it looks like a difference of about 13 hours. Could it be an issue with timezones? Is one of your routines using UTC and the other the local TZ ?